# SignalR v1.1.3. Hub could not be resolved during app startup after upgrade to server 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr, windows-server-2016

I've been tasked with migrating our Asp.Net MVC4 application running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server over to a Windows 2016 server.
 It works as expected on the 2008 server, but when I attempt to access the site on the 2016 server, a 500 error pops up stating

```
[InvalidOperationException: 'NotificationHub' Hub could not be resolved.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubManagerExtensions.EnsureHub(IHubManager hubManager, String hubName, IPerformanceCounter[] counters) +428
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ConnectionsManager.GetHubCOntext(String hubName) +295
   RR.DAL.SRepository.<.cctor>b__6() +87
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +734
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +189
   RR.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +748

[HttpException (0x80004005): 'NotificationHub' Hub could not be resolved.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +546
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +171
.....
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version: 4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version 4.8.4210.0
```

I have had no success so far with what I've discovered in other questions. 

[My hub class is marked as Public](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31729264/8119449)
[The SignalR route is added before the other routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/older-versions/signalr-1x-hubs-api-guide-server)
My hub classes are in the same assembly as the application
I've made sure that my web configuration has the validation and managed modules configured

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Ive configured extensionless URL's (carryover from the old server)
Our web.config targets 4.0 `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />'`
and the appplication pools on iis are all configured to use the 4.0 .net CLR versions
We are using Unity as well and the error occurs when registering and instance of our class that uses a hub

global.asax

```
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ISRepository), SRepository.Instance, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

SRepository.cs

```
namespace RR.DAL{
    public class SRepository : ISRepository{

        private readonly static Lazy<SRepository> _instance = new Lazy<SRepository>(() => new SRepository(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>().Clients));

        private SRepository(IHubConnectionContext clients){
            Clients = clients;
        }
        public static SRepository Instance{
            get{ return _instance.Value;}
        }
        private IHubConnectionContext Clients{get;set;}
```

NotificationHub.cs

```
public class NotificationHub: Hub
    {
        private readonly ISRepository _sRepository;

        public NotificationHub(ISRepository sRepository)
        {
            _sRepository = sRepository;
        }
```

I cant figure out why the application is crashing during the app_startup phase. I cant even view the /signalr/hubs page, it gives me the same error. 
Any ideas? 
The server is running IIS10, Windows Server 2016 with .Net Framework 4.6 The application is an MVC 4 .Net 4.0 and using SignalR v1.1.3

Comment: This error can result from using data types that cannot be discovered in a JSON payload, such as Array. The workaround is to use a data type that is discoverable by JSON, such as IList. For more information, see this link: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2672

Comment: @DingPeng I took a look at that link and it makes sense why it would need a datatype discoverable by JSON, but that looks like it has at least successfully started the application and was running. The issue appears to be occurring during the server startup and its unable to locate a hub that the SRepository is attempting to locate with the given IHubConnectionContext. I'm attempting to get debugging setup on the server to see if i can access that object since logging isn't outputting at that point yet